# Option to move Automatic Response emails except if the body contains text

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I see great responses on here about how to set up rules to move Automatic Responses to another folder.  I have one implemented, but ran into to an issue today where some one had included a request in the response that I didn't see and it created a problem for me.  All the options I can see for exceptions require specific text.  Since I have no idea what they might include in the response, is there any way to exclude it if there is any text in the response which I may need to review before ignoring?

Comment: include specific text? In this case, you can choose “except if the body contains specific words”. Otherwise, I’m afraid that there is no built-in option to realize this.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately I won't know what specific text they might include in their response.  Could be "Why are we meeting?", "Can we move to a different day?", "Send a bridge number since I'll be remote".  All of those responses would be something I'd not want to have moved off to my auto-response folder without looking at them.

Comment: Otherwise, I'm afraid that there is no built-in option to realize this.